# json file not loaded via angular threeJS

Tags: javascript, json, angular, three.js

I have made a simple model in blender and exported it as a json file to use on my app, i used angular cli to generate a base aplication where i added the threeJS, everything is working fine except i can't add my new model, it cannot find the json file dunno why, do i need to use http module with angular to accomplish this?
im a little confused

At the moment i have this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**my component**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }
  private container: HTMLElement;

  @ViewChild('container') elementRef: ElementRef;
  private scene: THREE.Scene;
  private camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
  private renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;

  private cube: THREE.Mesh;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.container = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

    console.log(this.container);

    this.init();
    this.http
  }

  init() {
    let screen = {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      color: 0xffffff
    },
      view = {
        angle: 45,
        aspect: screen.width / screen.height,
        near: 0.1,
        far: 1000
      };

    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(view.angle, view.aspect, view.near, view.far);
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1);

    this.scene.add(this.camera);
    this.scene.add(new THREE.AxisHelper(20));

    this.camera.position.set(10, 10, 10);
    this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    this.renderer.setSize(screen.width, screen.height);
    this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    var mesh = null;
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    this.http.get('assets/DAMA1.json');
    loader.load('./DAMA1.json', function (geometry) {
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
      this.scene.add(mesh);
    });

    let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5),
      material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: true });

    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    this.cube.position.set(-50, -50, -50);

    this.scene.add(this.cube);

    this.render();
  }

  render() {

    let self: AppComponent = this;

    (function render() {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
      self.renderer.render(self.scene, self.camera);
      self.renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1);

      self.animate();
    }());

  }

  onResize(event) {
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

  animate() {
    this.cube.rotateX(0.1);
    this.cube.rotateY(0.1);
    this.cube.position.addScalar(0.2);

  }


}
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are loading it twice with two distinct paths.

```
this.http.get('assets/DAMA1.json');
loader.load('./DAMA1.json');
```

Could be a path problem.

By the way, apparently, the function

```
 new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
```

accepts a json. If your assets are local, why dont you load them via imports, at the top of the file.

You could do:

```
import geometry from 'assets/DATA1.json';
```

And then, inside the component:

```
new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
```

If this solution doesnt work, can you catch the error throwed by the THREE loader? The loader function probably accepts a error callback.

Comment: can't load it that way, since angular need a module with that and if the json data is to big it need time to get it

Comment: Could you catch the error?


     .load ( url, onLoad, onProgress, onError )

The THREE.loader accepts a error callback in its 4th argument

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code :

1. Call loader.load(path_to_your_object) :

   `loader.load('assets/DAMA1.json');`
2. You should create material for your object

   `loader.load('assets/DAMA1.json',(geometry) => {
      mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material_for_your_object);
      this.scene.add(mesh);
   });`